# Sonata Admin Forms with dynamic fields

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

My EntryAdmin form needs three or four extra fields for different Campaigns defined by users and handled via entity CampaignProperties then appended via ajax dynamically when corresponding radio button is checked.

I have an EntryProperty table which then should store entry_id, property_id and value.

My intention was to save the extra fields on Entry entity's postPersist event.

I have extended the edit.html.twig which appends fields on the form fine but now I'm stuck when it comes to persisting as extra fields throw the error **'This form should not contain extra fields.'**.

Here is the code:
EntryAdmin form section

```
$formMapper
        ->add('channel', 'choice', array('attr' => array('class' => 'channels'), 'expanded' => true, 'choices' => $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Entry')->allowedChannels($security_context))) /* checks user-allowed campaigns to load extra campaign fields on check */
        ->add('name')
        ->add('tel', null, array('label' => 'Telephone'))
        ->add('email')
        ->add('deviceType', 'choice', array('expanded' => true, 'choices' => array('Smartphone', 'Feature phone')))
        ->add('createdAt', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array('label' => 'Posted on'))
        ->with('Items for sale')
            ->add('listings','sonata_type_collection', array(
            // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
            'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
        ))
        ->end()
        ->with('Photos')
            ->add('images','sonata_type_collection', array(
            // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
            'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
        ))
        ->end()
        ;
```

Extra fields twig loaded via ajax.

```
{% block fields %}
{% if(channel.properties) %}
    <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h4 class="box-title">
                Additional information
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="sonata-ba-collapsed-fields">
                {% for property in channel.properties %}
                    <div id="sonata-ba-field-container-{{ uniqId }}_{{ property.name }}" class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" class="control-label required">
                                {{ property.label }}
                        </label>
                        <div class=" sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
                            {% if(property.type == 'Text') and (property.length < 255) or (property.type == 'Number') %}
                                <input type="text" class=" form-control" maxlength="255" required="required" name="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" id="{{ uniqId }}_{{ property.name }}"> 
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if(property.type == 'Text') and (property.length > 255) %}
                                <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" id="{{ uniqId }}_{{ property.name }}"></textarea> 
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if(property.type == 'Boolean') %}
                                <ul class="list-unstyled channels" id="{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}">
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="">
                                            <div class="iradio_minimal" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">
                                                <input type="radio" value="0" required="required" name="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" id="{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}_0" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>No </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label class="">
                                            <div class="iradio_minimal" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">
                                                <input type="radio" value="1" required="required" name="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" id="{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}_1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                                                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>Yes </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if(property.type == 'Date') %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}_div' data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm">
                                        <input type="text" class="sonata-medium-date form-control" name="{{ uniqId }}['properties'][{{ property.id }}]" id="{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    jQuery(function ($) {
                                        $('#{{ uniqId}}_properties_{{ property.name }}_div').datetimepicker();
                                    });
                                </script>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Anyone with a idea how to solve this?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this covers your issue

```
  $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array(
    'type'         => new TagType(),
    'allow_add'    => true, <-- This Bit
));
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

### Updated 05/07/2016

Going by the updated Symfony **3.1** documentation you'd probably need something like this instead:

```
$builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => TagType::class,
    'allow_add'    => true,
));
```

Comment: My form is built through SonataAdmin's  FormMapper and the extra fields injected via Ajax. This approach seems to address manually built forms

Comment: I suggest you add some code then so we can see what is going on.

Comment: The option "allow_add" does not exist for sonata_type_model fields

Comment: Down voted because my 2 year old answer is NOW out of date?

Comment: I've updated now to reflect the up-to date documentation.